# Ppt file corrupted after restoring it from MySQL`s mediumblob

Tags: java, php, mysql, hibernate

I am re-writing legacy PHP app on Java Spring Boot. There is a mechanism to store and retrieve ppt files in MySQL db.
Php db insert:

```
$fsize = filesize($tmpFile);
$blob = addslashes(fread(fopen($tmpFile, "r"), $fsize));
$sql = "INSERT INTO tablename (id, pptSnapshot) VALUES ($id, '$blob')";
```

Php db retrieve:

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$sql = "SELECT pptSnapshot FROM tablename WHERE id=$id";
$result = runQuery($sql, "dm_prj");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"PWS_snapshot_$id.pptx\"");
echo $row['PPTSnapshot'];
```

And file is OK after this.

BUT

I am trying to get this file using Java:

Snapshot entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "prj_status_report_snapshots")
public class StatusReportSnapshot {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @Lob
    private Blob pptSnapshot;
    //getters setters
}
```

Service function:

```
 public byte[] getUserSnapshot(int id) throws Exception {
        StatusReportSnapshot snapshot = this.snapshotRepository.getSnapshotBySnapshotId(id).get();
        Blob blob = snapshot.getPptSnapshot();
        byte[] blobBytes = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
        return blobBytes;
    }
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/test/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody
    byte[] test(@PathVariable int id) throws Exception {
        return this.reportService.getUserSnapshot(id);
    }
```

I tried different approaches: map blob to String, byte[], Blob. Tried to save it to file system instead of return it to user through browser. Result is always the same -> extracted PPT file size is twice or more than expected and it is corrupted (can`t open it and see even blank page).

I am using the same db that I am using for php app. 
For php -> all works like a charm.

Thank you very much for any idea of how to solve it.
P.S. I am searching about 2 days and tested most common approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out what`s happend. 
The problem was in table encoding.